# Creating several Google Calendars and avoiding 403 : Rate Limit Exceeded

Tags: java, google-calendar-api, http-status-code-403, google-api-java-client, batch-request

I need to create up to 130 calendars on a Google account using Java and Google Calendar API but keep getting

> "403 : Rate Limit Exceeded".

What I've tried :

-looping with 
    service.insert(calendar).execute();
-> result : I receive error 403 after 25 inserts ( which weirdly enough seems to be the old limit, should be 60 according to : https://support.google.com/a/answer/2905486?hl=en )

-looping with delay between each request (up to 60 seconds)
->  result : Didn't change the outcome. still 403 after 25 inserts ( In its documentation about Exponential Backoff, Google talks about mere seconds so I should think 1 whole minute is enough even if I don't increase exponentially that delay ).

-Request Batching ( following [THIS](https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client-samples/blob/master/calendar-cmdline-sample/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/calendar/cmdline/CalendarSample.java) Google example code )
-> result : After about 10 callbacks the response falls into the onFailure method with.. You guessed it 403 status code.

I think I am well within my ( maxed-out ) API quotas most of the time. I've seen "quotaExceeded" only once after several tests.

Batch Request sample :

```
batch = this.service.batch();
JsonBatchCallback<Calendar> callback = new JsonBatchCallback<Calendar>(){
    @Override
    public void onFailure(GoogleJsonError e, HttpHeaders responseHeaders) throws HttpResponseException{
    log.debug(e);
    throw new HttpResponseException(Integer.valueOf(e.get("code").toString()), e.getMessage());
    }
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Calendar cal, HttpHeaders responseHeaders) {
    log.debug("Calendrier créé pour " + cal.getSummary());
    }
};

for( String user : usernameList ) {
    cal = new Calendar().setSummary(user);
    this.service.calendars().insert(cal).queue(batch, callback);
}
batch.execute();
```

Comment: have you tried increasing the quota limits in your project on the developer console?  BTW you shouldn't have to worry about backoff the library is designed to do that for you.  If you are getting rate limit exceeded you are going to fast.  You need to slow it down.   Also batching doesnt effect quota your still under the same quota limits with batching.

Comment: I increased all the quota limits to the maximum and this happens after only 10-25 requests. As you said the problem seems to be that I'm inserting "to fast" not exceeding quota limit (Response is 'Rate Limit Exceeded' not 'Quota Exceeded').
Well I didn't batch to decrease my impact on quotas, I did it so I only do one request instead of 1request/create. And Google shouldn't think I'm making too many requests/time to their server.
I've read that batching requests is useful exactly for that. making ONE big request that involves several Google actions on their side. instead of 1request/1action.

Comment: Not sure where you read that but my seven years of experience and contact with good developers says that batching dosent help with quota.   Rate limit exceeded is flood protection you are going to fast you need to send fewer request with the user at a time

Comment: I also said : " I didn't batch to decrease my impact on quotas ".
But yes I now understand that batching doesn't help in this case. Why doesn't it delivers each query when it can ?
 It seems crazy that even with 1 minute delay between each call I still hit the same 25 insert limit... Should I really let my application take the full day just to create the calendars I need ?

Comment: This is a free api you have to share with other developers.  this is what flood protection is for too ensure that we can all use the system